# Does every simply connected, orientable, non-compact, 3-manifold embed in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a simply connected, (orientable), non-compact, 3-manifold without boundary. Must $M$ be homeomorphic with a topological subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: You get orientable for free from the simply-connected assumption.    The answer to your question is almost certainly yes, but off the top of my head I do not know if this has been proven.  If your manifold is the universal cover of the interior of a compact manifold (with or without boundary) I believe the answer is known and yes.  For more complicated manifolds this is certainly an answerable question, but I don't see immediately how to assemble an answer.

Comment: The paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.02628.pdf discusses an open contractible 3-manifold that cannot be embedded into a compact 3-manifold, in particular, it cannot be embedded inro $\mathbb R^3$ (because then it would also embed into $S^3$).

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: this indeed answers my question as stated, thanks. Still...

Comment: @RyanBudney: for the application I have in mind, $M$ is in fact the universal cover of a compact 3-manifold. Could you provide details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the manifold is the universal cover of a compact $3$-manifold $M$ (to begin with, lets say without boundary) then you construct the embedding by hands, using geometrization.  In your question let's replace $\Bbb R^3$ with $S^3$ and we will see the embedding into $\Bbb R^3$ comes for free in the situation you are interested in.

An instructive case comes from the  case where your manifold is a connect-sum of lens spaces.   This has been the subject of a few recent threads:

[Universal covers of non-prime 3-manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419294/universal-covers-of-non-prime-3-manifolds/)

The basic idea is that you choose a collection of reducing spheres for the connect sum decomposition, call them $\Sigma$.  Then $M \setminus \Sigma$ is a disjoint union of punctured lens spaces.  Each of these have universal covers diffeomorphic to  punctured spheres, so they embed in $S^3$.  You then glue the embedded punctured spheres together (in $S^3$) so that the appropriate boundary spheres are glued together.  If you view the embedded punctured spheres from the perspective of their complements in $S^3$ we are essentially doing the canonical construction of a Cantor set.  There  is the exceptional case of $\Bbb RP^3 \# \Bbb RP^3$ where we are constucting the standard embedding $S^0 \to S^3$.

But this is the basic idea.  The remaining geometric 3-manifolds have universal covers that are also subsets of $S^3$, so you similarly glue these together along  the (lifted) torus decomposition or sphere decompositions.  The tori (being incompressible) will lift to copies of $\Bbb R^2$, so those gluings are a little easier to visualize.

Comment: Suppose $M$ is in addition 1-ended. Must it then be homeomorphic with $\mathbb{R}^3$?